# Dynamically change LinearLayout on a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a pretty basic fragment inside a ViewPager. The fragment contains a linearlayout. when i try to adjust the contents of the linearlayout I get a nullpointer exception from the linearlayout:

//Parent Activity (this contains the pager)

```
public void goToUnit(Unit unit) {

    ((UnitFragment) this._cupAdapter.getItem(1)).LoadUnitContent(unit);

    _pager.setCurrentItem(1, true);

}
```

//Fragment

```
public void LoadUnitContent(Unit latestUnit)
{
    this.set_unit(latestUnit);
    if(latestUnit != null) {
        View v = this.getView(); //-- this shows as null
        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.llExplanation);

    }
}
```

It seems all variables set in the onCreateView are now null when i try to access them from this method...

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you get NullPointerException because your ((UnitFragment) this._cupAdapter.getItem(1)) method return a newly created fragment each time you call this method.

So, if you call the LoadUnitContent() method right after it, the fragment hasn't been added yet to the ViewPager and the onCreate() method of the fragment has never been called so your view is null.

Just add Log.d("Fragment", "onCreate") and Log.d("Fragment", "LoadUnitContent") in your methods to see if LoadUnitContent is called first.